# Cloning extra slides for Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using [jQuery Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create a left-aligned, infinite, variable-width slider. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtaube/rLkj3wcn/2/

The basic initialization and settings, using the default theme:

```
$('.js-slick').slick({
    dots: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    arrows: true,
});
```

Here is the begginning of the slider, which appears as desired:

[image]

The problem is that when you reach the last slide there is a bunch of whitespace before the new slides pop in:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this? I need to remove the temporary white space flashing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... apparently this is a known bug with the [jQuery Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

There are some bug reports on GitHub, here is the most relevant one for anyone trying to subscribe to the issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1207

There are apparently some hacks posted in that GitHub report, but it didn't work well for me as it broke the 'dots' setting. I will update this answer if the bug is eventually solved. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Add    `infinite: false`

It will solve the white space issue as well as slider cloning issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have use these options:

```
infinite: false,
slidesToShow: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when i have 2 items per row. If you know the number of items that can be shown without scroll then you can set up a variable - in my case i could get 6 items on the screen without the need for a scroll

```
var infiniteScroll = true
if (noOfItems < 7)
{
infiniteScroll = false
}

$('.variable-width2').slick({
dots:true,
infinite: infiniteScroll,
draggable: true,
pauseOnHover: true,
swipeToSlide: true,
adaptiveHeight: false,
centerMode: false,
variableWidth: true,
arrows: false,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 2,
initialSlide: 1,
rows: 2,
responsive: [
{
          breakpoint: 1023,
          settings: {
            infinite: infiniteScroll,
            draggable: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            adaptiveHeight: false,
            centerMode: false,
            variableWidth: true,
            arrows: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
           // settings: "unslick"
          settings: {
            infinite: infiniteScroll,
            draggable: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            adaptiveHeight: false,
            centerMode: false,
            variableWidth: true,
            arrows: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        }]
    });
```